# How to convert a JSON string into a Python data structure

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, typeconverter

```
'[{"append":null,"appendCanExplainable":false,"appendList":[],"auction":{"aucNumId":"35179051643","auctionPic":"http://img.taobaocdn.com/bao/uploaded/i3/TB12WchGXXXXXb5XpXXXXXXXXXX_!!0-item_pic.jpg_40x40.jpg","link":"http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=35179051643","sku":"\xd1\xab\xb7\xd6\xc0\xe0:\xc9\xab\xbb\xd2\xcf\xdf\xbd\xf4\xc9\xed\xb3\xa4\xbf\xe3&nbsp;&nbsp\xb3\xdf\xc2\xeb:M-170M-55-62KG","thumbnail":"","title":"\xcb\xb9\xbd\xf4\xc9\xed\xbf\xe3 \xb5\xaf\xc1\xa6\xd7\xe3\xc7\xf2\xd4\xaf\xbd\xa1\xc9\xed\xbf\xe3 PRO \xc4\xd0 \xb4\xf2\xb5\xd7\xd1\xb5\xc1\xb7\xb3\xa4\xbf\xe3\xcb\xd9\xb8\xc9"},"award":"","bidPriceMoney":{"amount":35,"cent":3500,"centFactor":100,"currency":{"currencyCode":"CNY","defaultFractionDigits":2,"symbol":"\xa3\xa4"},"currencyCode":"CNY","displayUnit":"\xd4\xaa"},"buyAmount":1,"content":"\xba\xc3\xc6\xc0\xa3\xa1","creditFraudRule":0,"date":"2014\xc4\xea12\xd4\xc220\xc8\xd5 15:41","dayAfterConfirm":0,"enableSNS":false,"from":"","lastModifyFrom":0,"payTime":{"date":18,"day":4,"hours":13,"minutes":4,"month":11,"seconds":37,"time":1418879077000,"timezoneOffset":-480,"year":114},"photos":[],"promotionType":"\xbb\xee\xb6\xaf\xb4\xd9\xcf\xfa  ","propertiesAvg":"0.0","rate":"1","rateId":231421178840,"raterType":0,"reply":null,"shareInfo":{"lastReplyTime":"","pic":0,"reply":0,"share":false,"userNumIdBase64":""},"showCuIcon":true,"showDepositIcon":false,"spuRatting":[],"status":0,"tag":"","useful":0,"user":{"anony":true,"avatar":"http://a.tbcdn.cn/app/sns/img/default/avatar-40.png","displayRatePic":"b_red_3.gif","nick":"y***6","nickUrl":"","rank":65,"rankUrl":"","userId":"","vip":"","vipLevel":0},"validscore":1,"vicious":""},{"append":null,"appendCanExplainable":false,"appendList":[],"auction":{"aucNumId":"35179051643","auctionPic":"http://img.taobaocdn.com/bao/uploaded/i3/TB12WchGXXXXXb5XpXXXXXXXXXX_!!0-item_pic.jpg_40x40.jpg","link":"http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=35179051643","sku":"\xd1\xd5\xc9\xab\xb7\xd6\xc0\xe0:\xba\xda\xc9\xab\xba\xda\xcf\xdf\xbd\xf4\xc9\xed\xb3\xa4\xbf\xe3&nbsp;&nbsp\xb3\xdf\xc2\xeb:S-160m-45~55KG","thumbnail":"","title":"\xc7\xf2\xc9\xed\xbf\xe3\xb4\xf2\xb5\xd7\xd1\xb5\xc1\xb7\xb3\xa4\xbf\xe3\xcb\xd9\xb8\xc9"},"award":"","bidPriceMoney":{"amount":35,"cent":3500,"centFactor":100,"currency":{"currencyCode":"CNY","defaultFractionDigits":2,"symbol":"\xa3\xa4"},"currencyCode":"CNY","displayUnit":"\xd4\xaa"},"buyAmount":1,"content":"\xba\xc3\xc6\xc0\xa3\xa1","creditFraudRule":0,"date":"2014\xc4\xea12\xd4\xc220\xc8\xd5 15:37","dayAfterConfirm":0,"enableSNS":false,"from":"","lastModifyFrom":0,"payTime":{"date":17,"day":3,"hours":17,"minutes":43,"month":11,"seconds":47,"time":1418809427000,"timezoneOffset":-480,"year":114},"photos":[],"promotionType":"\xbb\xee\xb6\xaf\xb4\xd9\xcf\xfa  ","propertiesAvg":"0.0","rate":"1","rateId":231441191365,"raterType":0,"reply":null,"shareInfo":{"lastReplyTime":"","pic":0,"reply":0,"share":false,"userNumIdBase64":""},"showCuIcon":true,"showDepositIcon":false,"spuRatting":[],"status":0,"tag":"","useful":0,"user":{"anony":true,"avatar":"http://a.tbcdn.cn/app/sns/img/default/avatar-40.png","displayRatePic":"b_blue_3.gif","nick":"\xc2\xb7***0","nickUrl":"","rank":1235,"rankUrl":"","userId":"","vip":"","vipLevel":0},"validscore":1,"vicious":""}]'
```

How can I convert this str to list of dicts ? I have tried some methods, but failed. The string represents a list containing 2 big dicts, and one dict contains nested small dicts. The expected result is:

```
[{dict1},{dict2}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a *JSON string*, so use the [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) to decode this:

```
import json

decoded = json.loads(encoded)
```

`decoded` is then a Python list; you can then address each dictionary in a list, or use unpacking to assign two dictionaries to two names:

```
dictionary1, dictionary2 = decoded
```

If you are using the [`requests` library](https://requests.readthedocs.io/) then you can use the [`response.json()` method](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) to load the content:

```
decoded = response.json()
```

In this specific case you appear to have [GBK encoded data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GBK) however (or perhaps GB2312, a predecessor).

This goes well outside the JSON standard (which actually requires one of the UTF codecs to be used), and you'll need to tell `json.loads()` about the codec used:

```
decoded = json.loads(encoded, 'gbk')
```

The `requests` library will use whatever codec the server sent along with the response, or will otherwise use a characterset detection technique to try and find the right codec to use.

The result, when decoded, then looks like:

```
>>> decoded = json.loads(encoded, 'gbk')
>>> pprint(decoded)
[{u'append': None,
  u'appendCanExplainable': False,
  u'appendList': [],
  u'auction': {u'aucNumId': u'35179051643',
               u'auctionPic': u'http://img.taobaocdn.com/bao/uploaded/i3/TB12WchGXXXXXb5XpXXXXXXXXXX_!!0-item_pic.jpg_40x40.jpg',
               u'link': u'http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=35179051643',
               u'sku': u'\u52cb\u5206\u7c7b:\u8272\u7070\u7ebf\u7d27\u8eab\u957f\u88e4&nbsp;&nbsp\u5c3a\u7801:M-170M-55-62KG',
               u'thumbnail': u'',
               u'title': u'\u65af\u7d27\u8eab\u88e4 \u5f39\u529b\u8db3\u7403\u8f95\u5065\u8eab\u88e4 PRO \u7537 \u6253\u5e95\u8bad\u7ec3\u957f\u88e4\u901f\u5e72'},
  u'award': u'',
  u'bidPriceMoney': {u'amount': 35,
                     u'cent': 3500,
                     u'centFactor': 100,
                     u'currency': {u'currencyCode': u'CNY',
                                   u'defaultFractionDigits': 2,
                                   u'symbol': u'\uffe5'},
                     u'currencyCode': u'CNY',
                     u'displayUnit': u'\u5143'},
  u'buyAmount': 1,
  u'content': u'\u597d\u8bc4\uff01',
  u'creditFraudRule': 0,
  u'date': u'2014\u5e7412\u670820\u65e5 15:41',
  u'dayAfterConfirm': 0,
  u'enableSNS': False,
  u'from': u'',
  u'lastModifyFrom': 0,
  u'payTime': {u'date': 18,
               u'day': 4,
               u'hours': 13,
               u'minutes': 4,
               u'month': 11,
               u'seconds': 37,
               u'time': 1418879077000,
               u'timezoneOffset': -480,
               u'year': 114},
  u'photos': [],
  u'promotionType': u'\u6d3b\u52a8\u4fc3\u9500  ',
  u'propertiesAvg': u'0.0',
  u'rate': u'1',
  u'rateId': 231421178840,
  u'raterType': 0,
  u'reply': None,
  u'shareInfo': {u'lastReplyTime': u'',
                 u'pic': 0,
                 u'reply': 0,
                 u'share': False,
                 u'userNumIdBase64': u''},
  u'showCuIcon': True,
  u'showDepositIcon': False,
  u'spuRatting': [],
  u'status': 0,
  u'tag': u'',
  u'useful': 0,
  u'user': {u'anony': True,
            u'avatar': u'http://a.tbcdn.cn/app/sns/img/default/avatar-40.png',
            u'displayRatePic': u'b_red_3.gif',
            u'nick': u'y***6',
            u'nickUrl': u'',
            u'rank': 65,
            u'rankUrl': u'',
            u'userId': u'',
            u'vip': u'',
            u'vipLevel': 0},
  u'validscore': 1,
  u'vicious': u''},
 {u'append': None,
  u'appendCanExplainable': False,
  u'appendList': [],
  u'auction': {u'aucNumId': u'35179051643',
               u'auctionPic': u'http://img.taobaocdn.com/bao/uploaded/i3/TB12WchGXXXXXb5XpXXXXXXXXXX_!!0-item_pic.jpg_40x40.jpg',
               u'link': u'http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=35179051643',
               u'sku': u'\u989c\u8272\u5206\u7c7b:\u9ed1\u8272\u9ed1\u7ebf\u7d27\u8eab\u957f\u88e4&nbsp;&nbsp\u5c3a\u7801:S-160m-45~55KG',
               u'thumbnail': u'',
               u'title': u'\u7403\u8eab\u88e4\u6253\u5e95\u8bad\u7ec3\u957f\u88e4\u901f\u5e72'},
  u'award': u'',
  u'bidPriceMoney': {u'amount': 35,
                     u'cent': 3500,
                     u'centFactor': 100,
                     u'currency': {u'currencyCode': u'CNY',
                                   u'defaultFractionDigits': 2,
                                   u'symbol': u'\uffe5'},
                     u'currencyCode': u'CNY',
                     u'displayUnit': u'\u5143'},
  u'buyAmount': 1,
  u'content': u'\u597d\u8bc4\uff01',
  u'creditFraudRule': 0,
  u'date': u'2014\u5e7412\u670820\u65e5 15:37',
  u'dayAfterConfirm': 0,
  u'enableSNS': False,
  u'from': u'',
  u'lastModifyFrom': 0,
  u'payTime': {u'date': 17,
               u'day': 3,
               u'hours': 17,
               u'minutes': 43,
               u'month': 11,
               u'seconds': 47,
               u'time': 1418809427000,
               u'timezoneOffset': -480,
               u'year': 114},
  u'photos': [],
  u'promotionType': u'\u6d3b\u52a8\u4fc3\u9500  ',
  u'propertiesAvg': u'0.0',
  u'rate': u'1',
  u'rateId': 231441191365,
  u'raterType': 0,
  u'reply': None,
  u'shareInfo': {u'lastReplyTime': u'',
                 u'pic': 0,
                 u'reply': 0,
                 u'share': False,
                 u'userNumIdBase64': u''},
  u'showCuIcon': True,
  u'showDepositIcon': False,
  u'spuRatting': [],
  u'status': 0,
  u'tag': u'',
  u'useful': 0,
  u'user': {u'anony': True,
            u'avatar': u'http://a.tbcdn.cn/app/sns/img/default/avatar-40.png',
            u'displayRatePic': u'b_blue_3.gif',
            u'nick': u'\u8def***0',
            u'nickUrl': u'',
            u'rank': 1235,
            u'rankUrl': u'',
            u'userId': u'',
            u'vip': u'',
            u'vipLevel': 0},
  u'validscore': 1,
  u'vicious': u''}]
```

Comment: @Roger.H: since I cannot read Chinese, I had to verify that my guess at the codec was correct first; the first item title matched the URL title in any case.

Comment: @Roger.H: `requests` gives you a response object with a `json()` method: `decoded = response.json()`. It'll use the encoding the server sent you, if any, and otherwise will use a character set detection library to find the correct codec.